Spring Boot 3 SAML2 how to set maxAuthenticationAge
We have a legacy spring application which we've successfully moved to spring boot 3 using opensaml.
Here's a look at the dependencies:
dependencies {
    constraints {
        implementation "org.opensaml:opensaml-core:4.3.0"
        implementation "org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-api:4.3.0"
        implementation "org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-impl:4.3.0"
    }
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-saml2-service-provider'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.32'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.32'
}

Here's a look at the config class
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setResponseAuthenticationConverter(groupsConverter());

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                .requestMatchers("/saml2/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated());

        http.saml2Login(saml2 ->
                saml2.loginProcessingUrl(acsUrl)
                        .relyingPartyRegistrationRepository(relyingPartyRegistrationRepository())
                        .defaultSuccessUrl(successHandlerUrl));
        http.saml2Metadata(withDefaults());
        http.saml2Logout(withDefaults());
        http.httpBasic(withDefaults());
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository relyingPartyRegistrationRepository()
    {
        samlService.loadSamlConfigs();

        Collection<RelyingPartyRegistration> registrations = null;
        try
        {
            registrations = RelyingPartyRegistrations.collectionFromMetadata(resource.getInputStream()).stream()
                    .map(registration ->
                    {
                        String registrationId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                        return registration
                                .entityId(serviceProviderEntityId)
                                .registrationId(registrationId)
                                .assertionConsumerServiceLocation(String.join("", "{baseUrl}", acsUrl))
                                .signingX509Credentials(c -> c.add(credentialService.loadSigningCredential()))
                                .build();
                    })
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Collection<RelyingPartyRegistration> newRegistrations = registrations.stream().map(originalRegistration ->
        {

            String entityId = originalRegistration.getAssertingPartyDetails().getEntityId();
            String updatedRegistrationId = samlService.getOwnerIdentifier(entityId);

            return RelyingPartyRegistration.withRelyingPartyRegistration(originalRegistration)
                    .registrationId(updatedRegistrationId)
                    .build();
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new InMemoryRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository(newRegistrations);
    }

All of this works well. One of our clients needed a custom configuration with responseSkew set to 600 and maxAuthenticationAge over a month, we were able to achieve this before using this bean
<bean id="webSSOprofileConsumer" class="test.security.saml.TESTWebSSOProfileConsumerImpl">
        <property name="responseSkew" value="600"/>
        <property name="maxAuthenticationAge" value="31536000"/>
    </bean>

How can I achieve the same in the newer version. I have not found something similar. Thank you
